# Comparing data from 2 files using R

Tags: r

I have 2 files that contain benchmark results for the same test on 2 different hosts.  The results are raw data in space separated format.

I need to be able to compare them to each other as the hosts are not the same.  Primarily for the purposes of graphing.  Is there a way to add a "field" or column that is unique to each file (but the same to all rows in that file), which I can then use to differentiate the results in a graph?  How else could I go about doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just explicitly add in the extra column.

For example:

```
# first file
df1 <- read.table(...)
 # identify as first file
df1$file_name <- 'file1'

# second file
df2 <- read.table(...)
df2$file_name <- 'file2'

# combine:
df <- rbind(df1,df2)
```

Of course you don't need to do it in so many steps, but this should give you a starting direction.

Comment: This is throwing an error:  "Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names"

Comment: This is because your two data frames must have different column names -- your file 1 and file 2 have different column names. Set them to the same before merging (for example if `df1` has columns `a` and `c`, while `df2` has columns `a` and `b`, R won't combine `b` into the same column as `c` because they probably have different column names because they shouldn't be combined).

Comment: They had the same column names.  But I had defined the names of the columns after the rbind.  Moving that before fixed it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the general idea:

```
# Some example data
d1 <- read.table(text = "
a b
1 2
2 8
3 4", header=T)

d2 <- read.table(text = "
a b
1 3
2 10
3 5", header=T)

# Add an identifying column to each data.frame, then 'rbind()' them together
d1 <- data.frame(host = "host1", d1)
d2 <- data.frame(host = "host2", d2)
d <- rbind(d1, d2)

# Plot the results with your graphical system of choice
library(lattice)
xyplot(b~a, group=host, data=d, type="b", auto.key=TRUE)
```