# Is there a similar command in R to ' diff -y ' command in Linux?

Tags: r, compare, text-processing, date-comparison

As a newbie in `R`, I am wondering is there any `command` or `packages` in `R` which can provide and perform similar function in `Linux` as:

```
$ diff -y file01 file02
```

the `-y flag` is important because it can compare **side by side**.

I looked into some already asked questions such as [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132778/determining-different-rows-between-two-data-sets-in-r) [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29457222/how-can-i-compare-two-csv-file-in-r) [Q3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526354/comparing-data-from-2-files-using-r) and also the `compare package` but none is the one I am looking for!

Any help or suggestion is really appreciated.

Comment: You can make system calls with `system`, so `system("diff -y file01 file02")`

Comment: @Gregor Thnx for the help. However, when I did so I faced following 127 errors: Warning message:
running command 'diff -y file01 file02' had status 127 Any idea why? BTW, I am using RStudio , could it be the reason!

Comment: Works for me using RStudio on a simple test case. Searching for "status 127" turned up [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33646816/903061). Are you on Windows? If so, you'll need to [use a Windows equivalent](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6877238/903061).